# Cassandra CQL-Java Driver Making request via Proxy

Tags: java, proxy, cassandra, cql, nosql

I am using CQL java driver for my application. What I have to do is make the connection to the cluster via proxy. I am unable to find the required proeprty/settings.

Can someone help me with it? Is it possible to make connection to cassandra via proxy in cql driver?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to proxy your connection to cassandra?

Comment: Currently I am using CQL driver only for session connect and it works fine when proxy is not required. However my requirement is to proxy the request to cassandra, so not able to do the same with cql driver.

Comment: But what do you mean by proxy the request? This implies that you have some 3rd party application proxying connections from cassandra. If so, what problems are you having?

Comment: I have my cassandra in DC which is not accessible from the point where my application is deployed. So I need to proxy the request to make it work.

Comment: The problem I am facing is that I am unable to find any such setting or property in CQL driver to make it work.

Comment: The java driver can't act as a proxy, it is a client side driver, so you need to set up a proxy somewhere that you can talk to and can talk to the cassandra DC. Something like http://www.haproxy.org/

Comment: Assuming I have the IP address of proxy and port number to use,how can we set it to session.connect().

Comment: I have a tunnel connected to the dc. What I want to do is route the data using this as proxy so that cassandra can be reached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69303/discussion-between-mikea-and-learner).